# which features are most important for skin diseases classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-engineering, feature-extraction

I am working on skin problem detection and am using a skin image dataset. I want to extract features from the images, but I can't understand which handcrafted features I should extract. I did some research on it. There are many features with LBP, HOG, HUE, and so on. There are numerous. Do I need to remove and concatenate those before passing it to an algorithm? I mean, if I'm exacting HOG and LBP, will I merge them both and then give them on to the ML or DL algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

one approach could be to process the images with classic CNNs and the metadata/additional features separately, for example with a Fully Connected NN. The outputs from the two networks can then be concatenated and fed into an additional FC NN to generate the final predictions.

Check [this repo](https://github.com/naity/image_tabular) for the source code and further implementation details!

Comment: actually, I wanted to extract handcrafted features from the images, and merge that with the features extracted from CNN. But I think the repo you shared concatenates the image data with tabular data.